# Yii2 sum with group by in gridview not working

Tags: join, gridview, group-by, yii2, sum

Below is my query :

```
$query = AssignApplicant::find()
                ->select(['sum(total_pay) as sum','applicant.first_name','applicant.last_name'])
                ->joinWith(['position', 'applicant'])->orderBy(['job_positions.id' => SORT_DESC]);
 $query->groupBy(['applicant_id']);
```

My grid view

```
GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
            [
                'attribute' => 'applicant',
                'value' => 'applicant.first_name',
            ],
            'sum'
        ],
    ]);
```

This print null for the applicant.first_name. While when I run the raw query in the db it works. When I remove the below line it show the first_name but not the sum

```
->select(['sum(total_pay) as sum','applicant.first_name','applicant.last_name'])
```

Comment: mention table name with applican_id in group_by portion like table.applicant_id

Answer (score 1):

I solved by changing this :

```
 ->select(['sum(total_pay) as sum','`assign_applicant`.*'])
```